marketing cloud contact deletion mobile push
We are currently deleting contacts by the following rule.
(CustomerId - 12 digit numbers only)

SubscriberKey Like %-% (subscriber who cannot be defined) and DeviceID is NULL (Not App customer)
Msg sent 30 days is 0 or null and DeviceID is Null (Not App customer)

We have been using this rule for couple of months, and the average deleted records were 300~1000 per day.
We figured out that 290,000 contacts (almost 98% of All Contacts) has been deleted on last weekend but we cannot define the reason why.
We have already opened a support case but they couldn't help us much since the data was already deleted.
(Some of the deleted datas included customers who's SubscriberKey does not include %-% or have received a message in 30 days which does not comply with the rule)
Hence, I'm trying to figure out why there was a mass contact deletion, but it's hard to find one.
How can we re-import our mobilepush subscriber back to All contacts?
Based on the official reply from Salesforce is, to make customers re-install the app but that's quite impossible at this point.
Here are the 2 possible cases we can try at this point;

Import Contact Key,Platform,System Token,Device ID into MobilePush Push List
Create a new mobile push app in MobilePush Administrator and change the App Endpoint in SDK

Has anyone tried above before? Or has anyone deleted a mobilepush contact and tried to import them again?
Thank you
Best regards,
Luna

I don't know about #2 but you can always try #1 if you still keep these data, I am pretty sure this way will work.

@DucLe Thanks for the reply. Regarding #1, where can I retreive System Token? We only have DeviceId, OS Device and Contact Key in Data Cloud Bundle

If you don't have it now then you cannot. System tokens are uniquely provided by the phone and if you import then they have to be valid system tokens.  In the future, you can consider to store it somewhere (e.g. store it on SF CRM) when the app gathering opt-in from the user so you still have a backup for like this situation

@DucLe In case we have these 4 fields, and import them into Mobile List, does the current opt-in/opt-out status loaded by SDK is reflected in real time basis?
